# configure: error: libtool configure failed

Tags: tcl, libtool

I gave ./configure in tclreadline for tclreadline2.1.0 and got this error

```
loading cache ./config.cache
checking for a BSD compatible install... (cached) /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes    
checking whether make sets ${MAKE}... (cached) yes
checking for working aclocal... found
checking for working autoconf... found
checking for working automake... found
checking for working autoheader... found
checking for working makeinfo... found
checking whether make sets ${MAKE}... (cached) yes
checking host system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu': machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized

checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether the C compiler (gcc  ) works... yes
checking whether the C compiler (gcc  ) is a cross-compiler... no
checking whether we are using GNU C... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for Cygwin environment... (cached) no
checking for mingw32 environment... (cached) no
checking for executable suffix... (cached) no
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu': machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized

checking for ranlib... (cached) ranlib
checking for ld used by GCC... (cached) /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... (cached) yes
checking for BSD-compatible nm... (cached) /usr/bin/nm -B
checking whether ln -s works... (cached) yes
loading cache ./config.cache within ltconfig
checking host system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu': machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized

configure: error: libtool configure failed
```

Please suggest what to done to compile properly
Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 8):

Found the answer [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1232714&s=448ff6a3506ade10feba82d29d2518d7&p=11527952#post11527952). To get old `configure` scripts working, you can update the `config.sub` file:

```
curl 'http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.sub;hb=HEAD' > config.sub
```

This will replace the `config.sub` script with the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

The package looks like it hasn't been maintained in a long time. Consequently, the autotools used to build the configure script and auxiliary files probably aren't even aware of `x86-64`.

Assuming you have the autotools installed - autoconf, automake, libtool, etc. - you could try running `autoreconf -ivf`, and then attempting `./configure` again. You'll probably get a lot of warnings about out-of-date macros, etc. But it might work.